# more than one where condition in sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to execute the following query in pgSQL.

```
   select count(id) from master 
        where act1=true or act2=true
         and regn_no>2000;
```

But the query return all rows who satisfies the 'act1=true or act2=true' condition. It doesn't check act1=true or act2=true.Why?

SQLFIDDLE:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23b1f/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `AND` priority is higher than `OR` then sql parse your where clause as

```
(act1=true) or (act2=true
         and regn_no>2000);
```

---

you must rewrite your query as follow

```
select count(id) from master 
        where (act1=true or act2=true)
         and regn_no>2000;
```